# Make : Unexpected token error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am hitting following error while building my code.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `testk,x86_64'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (testk,x86_64)'
```

Code:

```
define temp
    mkdir -p $(@D)
ifeq ($(MACH),x86_64)
            env PERLLIB=/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 --test $< 
else
            env PERLLIB=/usr/ex-lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 --test $<
endif 
endef
```

I found we need to remove indentation before 'if' statement in make files. I did the same and still facing the issue. Can you please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

I am using 'temp' in following way.

```
$(TGT64)/$(SETUP): $(TGT64)/$(GEN_K)_gen
     $(temp)
```

Here I am trying to check the platform and set the environment accordingly. in 'define temp' I am check MACH variable content which has platform information.

I play around code and make following changes.

```
define temp
mkdir -p $(@D)
@ifeq ($(MACH),x86_64); then env PERLLIB=/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 $<; \
@else \ 
@env PERLLIB=/usr/ex-lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 $<; \
@fi
endef
```

This time I am facing.
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file issue.

Comment: What happens if you insert an `endif` before the `endef`?

Comment: How are you trying to run this code?

Comment: @APerson, Apologize.. endif is also there in my code. Just updated my question above.

Comment: That can't be your actual makefile, since you must have used `$(temp)` in your recipe not the constant `temp` as you show above.

Comment: Sorry , it was typo.. I just corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

Before we can help you have to show us how you're *using* this variable `temp` you've defined.  Just showing the contents of the variable won't help.

I expect that you're trying to use the variable inside a recipe, like this:

```
foo:
        $(temp)
```

You can't do that: the contents of a recipe have to be a shell script; recipes are passed to the shell to be executed.  The contents of `temp` as you've defined it contain makefile constructs which the shell doesn't know anything about, hence your syntax error from the shell.

Also, every line in a recipe is passed to a separate shell, so your line `env FOO = bar` has no effect: once that line has been invoked the shell exits and all changes to its environment are lost.

Your example here is not sufficient for us to recommend a workable strategy: you haven't told us what you want to accomplish.

*ETA* My answer above is still true.  It looks like you tried to convert your variable to contain shell script syntax for an if-statement, but did not complete the job: `ifeq` is makefile syntax not shell syntax.  In the shell, you have to use `if`.  Like this:

```
@if [ '$(MACH)' = x86_64 ]; then ...
```

However, please re-read my comment above about setting an environment variable... the recipe you've shown here will have no effect at all, even once it no longer has syntax errors.

Comment: Yes, your guess is correct. I am using that in same way.  I have updated my question with info..please check.

Comment: I played around code and made some changes...Updated above question.. Please check.